# WPF Dispatch Timer Starting at 0

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a little quiz and need to test how fast someone will do it. I would like the timer to start at 0 and then to count up from there so that the user can see how fast they are completing this said quiz.
I have the following code:

```
using System.Windows.Threading;
DispatcherTimer QuizTimer;
QuizTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
QuizTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
QuizTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(QuizTimer_Tick);

private void QuizTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblQuizTimer.Content = DateTime.Now.ToString("mm:ss");
        }
```

After searching the internet I haven't found any examples of where the dispatch timer is set to 0 and counts up. I understand that DateTime.Now means it's using the time that it is on computer right now and counting from there, but there are no other options that I have been able to see.

Answer (score 0):

Just store the DateTime when the timer is started:

```
private DateTime startTime;
...

startTime = DateTime.Now;
QuizTimer.Start();
```

and subtract it from the current time to get a TimeSpan:

```
private void QuizTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblQuizTimer.Content = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
}
```

---

As a note, in WPF you would usually use a TextBlock instead of a Label to display some text:

```
tbQuizTimer.Text = (DateTime.Now - startTime).ToString(@"mm\:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private readonly Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
...

stopwatch.Start();


private void QuizTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblQuizTimer.Content = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
}
```

The Stopwatch class allows you to Stop and Start and that would make this scenario a bit easier.